# Check if windows user login password request is enabled

Tags: windows, windows-registry, passwords, login, auto-login

For security reasons I would like to check if the current Windows user has a password set for his account and if this password is requested when Windows starts up (meaning that the auto login with saved password is deactivated).

Is there one or more registry keys that I can query for this purpose?

I would like to use this check as a pre-setup check in the installation routine of a software developed by me. I am aware that this is not a great protection measure. It is only about fulfilling a requirement that any user authentication is enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have write access to Group Policy. I only need this check as a pre-setup check, so that the software I developed is only installed in a "safe" environment and at least basic protection is available.

Comment: I hope you understand that a device that is configured to automatically log into a default user isn't necessarily insecure.

Comment: Very bad idea for software to dictate how the user should use his computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a domain environment, the values below in the following key would accomplish auto login:

HKLM\software\microsoft\windows nt\currenversion\winlogon\

- AutoAdminLogon = 1
- DefaultUserName = (username)
- DefaultDomainName = (domain)
- DefaultPassword = (password)

I suppose you only need to check AutoAdminLogon to make sure it's set to 0 (off) rather than 1 (on).

Edit: if you're worried about users not following security protocols for the environment in which you're developing production software for, and you don't have access to GPO's and such to enforce it yourself, you may want to have a chat with your sys/network admins for further reassurance